# Apache Cassandra - How to gain insight of data replication process (progress & status)?

Tags: cassandra, database-replication

Given a use case (just an example) that I'm trying to add a new datacenter "B" to an existing cluster "A", in order to replicate the data from A to B (with the desire to remove A *after* successful replication)... **how does one gain insight of the data replication process (progress & status)**?

To my knowledge & experience and of those around me, `nodetool netstats` seems to be a nice activity *indicator* but can’t be relied on for these insights. I don't seem to find a way nor an existing tool which is able to provide this insight. Am I missing something or is this simply not possible?

*p.s.: I've contacted DataStax and one of their recommended partners about this too - but unfortunately they only seemed interested selling me a managed solution instead of providing any insight regarding this question.*

Comment: Not sure if this is a useful answer, but we didn't find any tool to really monitor the progress. You can make some conclusions based on indirect things: fluctuations of free space, a size of owned data at `nodetool status` output, etc. `netstats` and `compactionstats` are useful here too. But all of them are indirect.

Comment: I'd add as a sidenote that same goes for most of the internal processes of Cassandra. E.g. we didn't find a way to directly monitor `rebuild` too.
Please refer to this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25081283/2689097) for further info.

Comment: @doz10us - Well, I guess it's always interesting to know that others (so far) seem to conclude the same.